# How to take SQL Server database backup from an ASP.NET Core online application?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, database-backups

I need to take SQL Server database backup from an ASP.NET Core web application and store the backup file to my local computer drive in path `C:\DatabaseBackupFile\DatabaseName.bak`.

Here is my code:

```
public IActionResult TakeDatabaseBackup()
{
        try
        {
           //  var connectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Data Source=SQLEXPRESS";

           var connectionString = "Data Source=SQLOnlineWebServer.com;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User Id=DatabaseUserName;Password=123456789";

            var backupFolder = System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:/DatabaseBackupFile/").ToString();

            var sqlConStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
            var backupFileName = String.Format("{0}{1}-{2}.bak",
                backupFolder, sqlConStrBuilder.InitialCatalog,
                GetLocalDateTime().ToString("MM-dd-yyyy-hh-mm-tt"));
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConStrBuilder.ConnectionString))
            {
                var query = String.Format("BACKUP DATABASE {0} TO DISK='{1}'",
                sqlConStrBuilder.InitialCatalog, backupFileName);

                using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            return Json(new { type = "success" });
        }
        catch
        {
            return Json(new { type = "error" });
        }
}
```

When I run the above code to take database backup, I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open backup device 'C:\DatabaseBackupFile\databaseName.bak'. Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
> BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Please guide me how to change the above code to take database backup from online server and save it to my local computer drive the following path `C:\DatabaseBackupFile\databaseName.bak` ?

Thank you

Comment: Is that SQL Server a **remote** server - i.e. running on another server somewhere? You **cannot** do database backups from a remote server to a local disk - backups are always done **on the server machine** where SQL Server runs

Comment: yes exactly I am trying give a link to the user when to take database backup from a remote server and save it to the specified local computer drive folder,  How can I do that to allow the application admin user to take back from their data, the user doesn't have access to remote control panel,  so they need to use application UI to take backup @marc_s

Comment: @marc_s You can backup locally then copy it off. Or you can use a VDI provider (but that's obviously out of scope for [so])

Comment: Side note: `BACKUP DATABASE` is fully parameterizable, do **not** inject the database and file names, use parameters instead.

Comment: Currently, I am getting back-up from my remote server Cpanel, then download the backup and save it on my local computer drive, So I can do this because I am the admin of the remote hosting control panel, But my client is saying to give us access that we can download backup from their UI application, The client do not have access to remote hosting Cpanel @Charlieface

Comment: So you need to work out a way for your web application to access that location as well as for SQL Server to be able to access it.

Comment: I have written the above code that client can take backup from the application UI, but that code work only if the database connection string associated with local database, when I change the connection string to connect to the remote database and take backup it give the above error 'Cannot open backup device' If you can please share some link or resource to achieve this @Charlieface